# Open ViewPager views beyond max count set in the Fragment Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I have a viewPager with 4 view, which I can access by swiping left or right.  My Adapter -

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


    public MyAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                return new FirstFrag();
            case 1:
                return new SecondFrag();
            case 2:
                return new ThridFrag();
            case 3:
                return new FourthFrag();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Since getCount() return 3 hence I can only see only three views which is fine and it works perfectly but I go to the fourth view maybe programatically, beyond the fixed count.

Why I am doing this? I am trying to make a view accessible when user click a button on the third view but can't access it by swiping. I have tried launching an new activity but the problem was my livedata viewmodel data couldn't talk to the new activity because two activities can share viewmodel hence this approach.

My solution was, the approach I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you are indicating that there are only 3 views, ignoring a fourth, remember that in programming the 0 does count.

Your solution is

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


    public MyAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                return new FirstFrag();  //View 1
            case 1:
                return new SecondFrag(); //View 2
            case 2:
                return new ThridFrag();  //View 3
//By indicating that getCount () return 3, this is all 3 views
            case 3:
                return new FourthFrag(); //View 4
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount () {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should read my question carefully. I under what count from zero. That's not my problem. I want to restrict the access of the forth view from swiping but make it accessible on click.